# Using regex in Java Split to string into tokens and return only one token

Tags: java, regex, string

Using Java's split string method, I know you can split a string into tokens by a delimiter, but is there a way you can return only one specific token using regex?

For example, if I have the following string: 'item1|item2|item3|item4'
Is there a way to construct a regex to return say token 1 (item1) or token 4 (item4)?

> I know it can be done in multiple lines of code, but I wanted to know
>   specifically if it could be done using regex only.

**Further explanations**
I don't believe I have accurately explained my issue so I'll expand this information.

The text comes from a database and contains reference data. The programmer doesn't know how long this data is, or how many tokens it may contain.
For example, the data could contain the following:

```
ENGLAND|44|ENG|EN
```

A programmer will want to call a method which gets a particular decode from this list. For example, they may want to get decode 1 (ENGLAND), they may want decode 4 (EN)
I wanted a regex solution which would work to return any token if it exists. Separate regex's is not a solution to this issue, because we don't know how many decodes could be in the list. (There could in theory be hundreds) I wanted to know if there was a simple way we could tell regex split into tokens, then give me token X, without splitting into an array, then returning array element X.

Comment: The `split` invocation will return an array. You can just pick the element at the index you choose.

Comment: *if it could be done using regex only* yes

Comment: you can indeed create a `regex` which matches only the specific item, but as it Mena already said is the best way

Comment: I know how to access arrays, my question specifically said without using arrays. I wanted to know if you could specify in the regex to only return a specified token.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer "you can indeed create a regex which matches only the specific item"
My question was HOW do I do this. I don't know the regex to do this.

Comment: The 4th item has 3 `|`'s in front of it - that should be enough of a hint to get you started (assuming you know enough about regex - if not, you're probably getting a bit ahead of yourself).

Comment: I don't know anything about RegEx, that's why I'm asking here. But I'll have a look using your information to see if I can find a solution. :)

Comment: it depends on the item. for every itemyou will need a different regex. a regex to match "item1" would be `item1`

Comment: " for every itemyou will need a different regex" Thank you, that means the answer to my question (which I believe I've failed to accurately describe) is no. You can't use regex to return a specific token from a string. - Basically, I wanted to read a pipe delimited string from a database, and using regex return a specific token from that list in a single  command without knowing what the token was. If you need specific regex to do this rather than say return token 2, or token 5 then it doesn' fulfil my needs. - Thanks for the responses anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

given the string item1|item2|item3|item4

- item1

```
^[^|]*
```

- item4

```
[^|]*$
```

- item2

```
(?<=\|)[^|]*(?=(?:\|[^|]*){2}$)
```

can be checked [here regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eWJNsR/1)

how item2 works

- `(?<=\|)` look behind to assert match starts after a litteral `|`
- `[^|]*` matches 0 or more characters except `|`
- `(?=(?:\|[^|]*){2}$)` asserts that there are exactly 2 `|` until end of line

Java code to extract item2

```
    String str = "item1|item2|item3|item4";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "(?<=\\|)[^|]*(?=(?:\\|[^|]*){2}$)" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( str );
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println( m.group() );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't entirely answer my question. (I understand that my question wasn't explained as completely as I should have to completely get across my needs.) - I needed to return a specific token by number when the string to split contains 0, 1 or many tokens.

Comment: can you explain more exactly what you are trying to do with minimal example : input and expected output?

Comment: I have edited my original question with additional information.